# Strange behaviour of program

Tags: c++, mpi, hdf5

I have a MPI program which does parallel I/O using HDF5 library. I have encountered a strange problem when debugging. I have tested for memory leaks using valgrind for a simple test case and no errors are reported. I then try another test case using 120, 240, 360 and 480 cores. All cases run except for the 120 cores case where I get this error:

```
 MPI: MPI_COMM_WORLD rank 108 has terminated without calling MPI_Finalize()
 MPI: aborting job
 MPI: Received signal 9
```

I am puzzled by this. What does the error mean? Can it be because of insufficient memory?

Comment: Looks like some of your workers didn't terminate correctly. Can you be absolutely sure that all nesessary cleanup (calling `MPI_Finalize()`) is actually done?

Comment: @ulidtko I do not get any errors when using > 120 cores!!

Comment: @SumanVajjala Thats not a very good argument. There is nothing magical about 120 cores.

Comment: Signal 9 is `SIGKILL`. Probably your program runs too slow with 120 cores and runs over its time limit if you use some sort of batch processing software (LSF, Torque, PBS, SGE, etc.) It could also be exhausting other job limits (memory for example).

Comment: @HristoIliev Thanks Hristo for your inputs. At first I guessed my program was giving a seg fault. But after testing with valgrind, it occured to me that it could be due to memory exhaustion.

Comment: @Mikhail I never said 120 cores was a magic number!! It so happens that for a particular test case 120 cores gave this error, that's all. I posted this error in this forum and got replies saying there is a problem with the code (seg fault), which, anyway, I could not find!!

Comment: Program errors result in signals like `SIGSEGV`, `SIGILL` or `SIGBUS`. `SIGKILL` is used to unconditionally terminate a process and that's what many batch systems use in order to end jobs that have reached past the end of their granted timeslot.